# Getting last ten codepad.org posts with Easy Html Parser (EHP) python

Tags: python, html, parsing, scraper

I have found a python html parser that builds a dom like structure
for html sources it seems easy to use and very fast. i'm trying to write a scraper for codepad.org that retrieves the last ten posts from
http://codepad.org/recent

The EHP lib is at https://github.com/iogf/ehp
i have this code below that is working.

```
import requests
from ehp import Html

def catch_refs(data):
    html = Html()
    dom = html.feed(data)

    return [ind.attr['href']
                for ind in dom.find('a')
                    if 'view' in ind.text()]

def retrieve_source(refs, dir):
    """
    Get the source code of the posts then save in a dir.
    """
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    req  = requests.get('http://codepad.org/recent')
    refs = catch_refs(req.text)
    retrieve_source(refs, '/tmp/')
    print refs
```

it outputs:

```
[u'http://codepad.org/aQGNiQ6t', 
 u'http://codepad.org/HMrG1q7t', 
 u'http://codepad.org/zGBMaKoZ', ...]
```

as expected but i cant figure out how to download the source code of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `retrieve_source(refs, dir)` don't do anything.

So you are not getting any result.

Update according to your comment:

```
import os


def get_code_snippet(page):
    dom = Html().feed(page)
    # getting all <div class=='highlight'>
    elements = [el for el in dom.find('div')
                if el.attr['class'] == 'highlight']
    return elements[1].text()

def retrieve_source(refs, dir):
    for i, ref in enumerate(refs):
        with open(os.path.join(dir, str(i) + '.html'), 'w') as r:
            r.write(get_code_snippet(requests.get(ref).content))
```

Comment: yeah but it gives me the html i need just the source code that was posted, get it?

Comment: huh, you haven't properly clarified about `source code`, so it looks like source code of page. For snippets with source code you actually need to write parsing part.